# How to get the decimals of ERC20 Token in smart contract

Tags: solidity

I have a smart contract which operates with an "external" ERC20 Token. For some calculations I need to access the `decimal()` function of the ERC20 Token.

In my contract I have the following line:

```
price = 200 * (10 ** token.decimals());
```

When I want to compile I get this error: `TypeError: Member "decimals" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract IERC20.`

I initialize the "external" Token through the constructor:

```
IERC20 private token;

constructor(IERC20 _token) public {
    token = _token;
}
```

Does anyone know how to get access to the decimals of the token?

Comment: What is `IERC20` in your code?

Comment: Are you sure the token should support such functionality? `decimals` is an optional property in ERC20: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md

Comment: The openzeppelin IERC20 Interface: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol

Comment: Also, be aware that `decimals` is primarily designated for off-chain use (typically in order to achieve nicer display of huge values). Using it on-chain is rather unusual, so you might wanna consider that very carefully (i.e., think what your goal is, and why you need to use this value in order to achieve that goal).

Comment: And there is obviously no `decimals` function in that interface, in case you haven't noticed.

Comment: price should be the price of one good. So I have to take the decimals into account, haven't I?

Comment: No, you should do everything in wei, and use `decimals` only in your dapp, when you display prices to users.

Comment: But if the token hasn't 18 decimals?

Comment: In your dapp, get the decimals of the token. Every input received from the user should be multiplied by `10**decimals` before passed to the contract. Every output received from the contract, should be divided by `10**decimals` before passed (or displayed) to the user.

Comment: Ok! So the better way would be to change the value of `price` directly to 200.000.000.000 if the external token has 9 decimals?

Comment: Possibly, I am not familiar with your entire system (contracts and application code). Side note: Please start accepting answers given to you here. You've asked about 10 questions, but you haven't accepted a single answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will allow you to call `decimals` on every token which implements this method (either explicitly, or implicitly as a public variable):

```
contract IERC20Extented is IERC20 {
    function decimals() public view returns (uint8);
}

contract MyContract {
    IERC20Extented private token;

    constructor(IERC20Extented _token) public {
        token = _token;
    }

    ...
}
```

Be aware that `decimals` is primarily designated for off-chain use (typically in order to achieve nicer display of huge values).

Using it on-chain is rather unorthodox, so you might wanna consider that very carefully (i.e., think about your goal, and ask yourself why you need to use this value in order to achieve that goal).

Comment: A better declaration for the IERC20Extended: ```abstract contract IERC20Extented is IERC20 {
    function decimals() public virtual view returns (uint8);
}```